# Run Target when dependent project is build

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj, msbuild-task

I have a ASP.NET project with a HTTP API and a classlib as a client project. I'm generating a .NET client with NSwag using a MSBuild task.

My goal is that

- the client is generated before the build of the client project (to ensure that the compilation runs properly)
- the client is only generated when the API changes

My current attempt is to have a pre compilation task in the client project with a project reference to the API project without referencing the output assembly:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Backend\Presentation\Web.csproj" ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="NSwag" BeforeTargets="BeforeCompile" Condition="'$(CI)' != 'true'">
    <Exec Command="$(NSwagExe_Net60) run client.nswag.json /variables:Configuration=$(Configuration) /variables:OutputType=Exe" />
</Target>
```

I already tried some various targets already but I'm struggling to find a target that suits my use case. My current approach does not build the client when the API project is build. I have to make changes to the client project in order to ensure that it is build or execute a rebuild.

Is there any target that could fit my use case?

Comment: And what doesn't work? Your approach seems reasonable to me

Comment: @mu88 sorry, I clarified my issue in the question.

Comment: Try the `BeforeBuild` target instead of `BeforeCompile`

Comment: @mu88 I also tried out `BeforeBuild` but with no success.

Comment: Is `BeforeBuild` called?

Comment: Yes but just the dependent project is build but not the client project.

Comment: In case any weary travelers come across this in the future looking for the syntax for setting variables, they go like this: `/variables:Variable1=MyValue1,Variable2=MyValue2,VariableN=MyValueN` https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/CommandLine for more detail